# Which Java exception should I use?

Tags: java, exception

Let's assume I'm a complete lazy bum and I don't want to invest the several dozen keystrokes needed for my own exception class (it's not utterly important which gets used, really).  However, to pretend I'm following good practices here, I want a pre-existing one that best fits my situation.

**Problem:** I need to throw an exception when my class's constructor receives an object in its parameters that is not found within a given list I've built elsewhere.

Which exception class would be appropriate to throw for that?

Comment: As an additional comment. Most of the times it is better to re-use existing exceptions that create a new one.

Comment: Hence why I asked.  There be a lot of subclasses, though: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`IllegalArgumentException`

Answer (score 12):

Winner by Accuracy:
[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html)

Answer (score 10):

IllegalArgumentException is indeed the answer here, but I'd say you have a problem with your design.  In essence, your class invariant is dependent on the state of some external object, which is a violation of encapsulation.  There's no way to determine whether a call to your constructor will succeed without knowledge of some *other* object, which leads to a confusing and easily misused API.

This problem is mitigated somewhat if the list you refer to is a `static final` unmodifiable List (see `java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList()`) and contained within the class in question, but I still don't like it terribly much.  Better is to encapsulate, if possible, the acceptable parameter values in an `enum`, which will eliminate the need for an exception altogether.  I generally dislike exceptions thrown from constructors.  If you must throw an exception, use a factory method instead.

If an option is not available to you that eliminates the need for an external list, you may need to rethink your design.

Comment: +1.  In addition, if he absolutely has to have such an error prone API, then creating his own checked exception may help guide the API client to proper coding practices.

Comment: It's a private nested inner class.  That's as good of an encapsulation as I can manage within Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't fear an explosion in the number of classes, you can extend the `IllegalArgumentException` for this situation.

```
 public class InvalidInstance extends IllegalArgumentException{
    private String[] parameter;

    public InvalidInstance (String[] param){
        this.parameter = param;
    }

    public String getMessage()
    String msg = "YOUR_MESSAGE";
    /* I think a string as "The currente object is
       invalid for parameter "+cycle for over parameter;*/
    msg += super.geTMessage();
    return msg;
}

public Constructor(parameter1,...){
    String[] param = new String[number_parameters]
    if...
    throws new InvalidInstance(param);
}
```

In this way, you can log all the parameters what run the exception.

This code isn't very beautiful to read: you can use if you prefer the very structured code. A simple `IllegalArgumentException` is more common :)

Answer (score -2):

Just in case you didn't get it, IllegalArgumentException :)